# How to indicate the index when storing hashing table?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

You need to store some numbers in a hash table. Collisions are handled by the closed hashing method (no
chaining). The table has 4 buckets, and the hash function is KmodN, where N is the number of buckets.
The commands to store the items are show below, and are executed in the order given.
Which bucket (index) will the number 8 be stored in?

```
hashtable.add(2)
hashtable.add(4)
hashtable.add(6)
hashtable.add(8)
```

I hope it is simple as I think so I would go with 0 ?

Comment: I think you must also know the size of a bucket, then you're ready to go. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 0):

**Closed hashing method** means that only 1 item/bucket. There is no chaining that is done. Therefore,`hashtable.add(2)` would make the bucket `position 0` occupied.

Now `hashtable.add(8)` would also hash to bucket `position 0`. This is a **collision**.

In closed hashing, there is a rehash strategy, where we try other positions given by other hash functions and if a blank position is found, we fill the item in that position and if we are unable to find any blank position, we declare the hash table to be full.

So, if your rehash functions hash to `position 3`, the item will go to that bucket, otherwise it will declare the hashtable to be full. But nothing can be said with certainity unless you state your rehash strategy.